# how to set a bitmap as a mask

Tags: actionscript-3

i want to apply a picture which contains transparent areas as a mask to a display object.
the mask only show the area which the mask has color.but in fact,the display object still show the whole area.so i convert bitmap to a vector image,that's solve the problem,but the convert method is horrible.

```
    public static function createVectorImage(bd:BitmapData,colorKey:uint = 0):Shape{

        if(bd==null){
            return null;
        }
        var sh:Shape = new Shape();
        var g:Graphics = sh.graphics;
        g.beginBitmapFill(bd);
        var beginPixel:int  = -1;
        var i:int,il:int,j:int,jl:int;
        var value:uint;
        for(i = 0,il=bd.height;i<il;i++){
            for(j = 0,jl = bd.width;j<jl;j++){
                value = bd.getPixel32(j,i);
                if(value!=colorKey&&beginPixel==-1){
                    beginPixel = j;
                }else if(value==colorKey&&beginPixel!=-1){
                    //draw rect
                    g.drawRect(beginPixel,i,j-beginPixel,1);
                    beginPixel = -1;
                }
            }
            if(beginPixel!=-1){
                g.drawRect(beginPixel,i,j-beginPixel,1);
                beginPixel = -1
            }
        }
        g.endFill();

        return sh;
     }
```

is there any way better than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to use [bitmap caching](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#cacheAsBitmap). It needs to be applied to the mask as well as the maskee:

```
var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(200, 200, true, 0x00000000);
bd.fillRect(new Rectangle(0, 0, 40, 40), 0xff000000);

var mask:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bd);
mask.cacheAsBitmap = true;

var maskee:Sprite = new Sprite();
maskee.cacheAsBitmap = true;
maskee.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000, 1);
maskee.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
maskee.graphics.endFill();
maskee.mask = mask;

addChild(mask);
addChild(maskee);
```

Comment: i already tried this way ,but i failed because i didn't add mask to the display list addChild(mask),make things different

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your display object to a bitmap then apply a mask on it.

1. Convert you display object to a bitmap data:

   ```
   var rect:Rectangle = displayObject.getRect();
   var displayBD:BitmapData = new BitmapData(rect.width, rect.height, true, 0);

   displayBD.draw(displayObject);
   ```
2. Apply the mask:

   ```
   private static const ORIG:Point = new Point(0, 0);
   private static function createBitmapDataWithMask(
           baseBD:BitmapData, maskBD:BitmapData):BitmapData
   {
       var bitmapData:BitmapData;

       bitmapData = new BitmapData(baseBD.width, baseBD.height, true, 0x000000);
       bitmapData.copyPixels(baseBD, baseBD.rect, ORIG, maskBD, ORIG, true);

       return bitmapData;
   }
   ```
3. Display the bitmap data:

   ```
   var bitmapData:BitmapData = createBitmapDataWithMask(displayBD, maskBD);
   var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData, "auto", true);

   addChild(bitmap);
   ```
4. If you remove the bitmap from the stage, don't forget the free the bitmap data!

   ```
   removeChild(bitmap);
   bitmap.bitmapData.dispose();
   bitmap = null;
   ```